# good monitor for linux photo editing

Tags: linux, desktop, monitors, video, compatibility

I'm looking for a monitor to do photo editing on Linux. I have been really impressed by the [Apple iMac 5k displays](https://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/imac/27-inch-imac-with-retina-5k-display): the display is really sharp and the colors are really amazing. Obviously, I won't switch to a Mac because of this: I have other constraints (namely, my freedom). So I wonder if I should take the leap into the 4k world. I'm concerned about my computer (an [Intel NUC BOXNUC6I3SYH](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/boards-kits/nuc/kits/nuc6i3syh.html)) not being fast enough to drive such a display. I'm also concern about everything looking too small because of 4k support missing from my distro (Debian GNU/Linux "stretch", running under Xmonad).

I'm especially wondering about the color gamut: it seems that most monitors do not care about giving you a full Adobe RGB coverage. Maybe I don't understand this correctly, but it seems it would be better to have 100% Adobe RGB than 100% sRGB color space, although I must admit I am mostly working with sRGB these days. Should I care?

Otherwise my specs are fairly modest: I have a [HP L2245wg](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-l2245w-22-inch-widescreen-lcd-monitor/3648391/drivers), a 22" display that's serving me well. I like the rotative feature, but I could live without that swivel, especially since there doesn't seem to be a way to auto-rotate the display.

Thanks for any recommendation.

Comment: Adobe RGB is a superset of sRGB. And better monitors do give those specs, you just have to search hard enough (manufacturer's website). 100% sRGB is roughly 70% Adobe RGB, but 80% Adobe RGB might be less then 100% sRGB (unlikely).